# Recriar tabelas sem dropar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela já populada. Nela há um campo not null, que eu preciso setar para null. Em modo gráfico não aceita e diz que eu tenho que recriar a tabela. Há como fazer isso sem que eu tenha a necessidade de dropar a tabela e ainda manter os dados? Há alguma forma para isso?

Comment: Qual a mensagem que dá?

Comment: Deve ter um método de copiar os dados da tabela e salvá-los em um arquivo externo, assim você pode `dropar` e recriar a tabela...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute uma query para alterar a tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE [table-name] ALTER COLUMN [column-name] [type] NULL
```

Comment: Resolveu Luis Henrique, mas porque em modo design eu não consigo? Não entendi.

Comment: Sinceramente nesse caso não sei porque em transact-sql ele permite. O design bloqueá pois é uma das 4 ações não permitidas quando se está com o modo de proteção ativado.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx

Comment: O design deveria permitir está ação, visto que alterar de not-null para null não causa nenhum efeito colateral. Por isso sou adepto de que validações devem ser feitas em nível de aplicação, banco de dados só para guarda-los mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

Infelizmente não.
Porem você pode em: `Ferramentas` > `Opções` > `Designers`
Então desmaque a opção: `Evitar salvas alterações que exijam recriação de tabela`

Desta forma o Sql Manager irá criar uma nova tabela temporia, mover os dados para ela, dropar a antiga e renomear a temporaria para o nome definitivo.